# Getting first word after comma in a string with varying length in Python

Tags: python, split

I have a Variable like this:

```
**Name**
Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)
Allen, Mr. William Henry
...
```

I want to extract the first word after comma.

This works for me, but it takes 2 dataframe steps:

```
train_df1=train_df['Name'].str.split(',',expand=True)
train_df2=train_df1[1].str.split(' ',expand=True)[1]
```

train_df contains the variable 'Name'

Comment: can you use regex?

Comment: So you try to get `Miss`, `Mrs` and `Mr` from your text sample ?

Comment: @Frodon . yes I want to extract the salutation

Comment: Could you put your variable in Python syntax, too, please? It is hard to see what `train_df` or `train_df['Name']` is supposed to be. If you give your input in Python syntax, you make it easier for others to provide working code. Also efficiency depends a lot on the data structures used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to get this.

```
import re
s="Heikkinen, Miss. Laina"
re.findall(r'(?<=,\s)[a-z]+',s,re.I)
```

If the format of the string is consistent (word followed by a `,` followed by a space followed by space separated words), use

```
[i for i in s.split()][1]
```

Comment: Thanks,Can you please suggest a simpler solution?

Comment: How do I apply this on dataframe: I tried this, but does not seem to work:  x=train_df['Name'][i for i in s.split()][1]

Comment: `x=[i for i in train_df['Name'].str.split()][1]` ?

Comment: This does not seem to work, only in some rows, values are coming as expected

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.partition` and `str.split`.

```
s = 'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina'
s.partition(',')[-1].split()[0] # 'Miss.'
```

Comment: can you please site an example on the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add in a one liner assuming that your string is separated by newline characters and the first line is a header of some kind:

```
salutations = [x.split(", ")[1].split(".")[0] for x in string.split("\n")[1:]]
```

Just if you don't want to do the regex solution

Answer (score 0):

i = str.index(",")
newStr = str[i:]